# Casting a generic instance to a non generic one

Tags: c#, generics, types

I have a class defined as following:

```
class ProxyWithSetter<T> : ProxyValue where T : Value
```

It has a field of the type

```
Action<T> Setter;
```

Say I have a list of `ProxyValue` instances, some of which are also `ProxyWithSetter`, how can I pass an object, with a type that's a subclass of `Value`, to one of those `ProxyValue`s that I determine is a `ProxyWithSetter`?

The problem here is that I need to cast one of those `ProxyValue`s into a `ProxyWithSetter`, but the cast also requires a type parameter. Which I can't provide because the **EXACT** type of the object I'm going to pass to the function **isn't known at compile time**. I only know that it is a subtype of `Value`, as it should be.

Basically, I wanted to do this

```
(p as ProxyWithSetter<Value>).Setter(val);
```

The cast returns null because `p` isn't of type `ProxyWithSetter<Value>`, but there's no way to know the exact type it is. I also don't know the **EXACT** type of `val`. Just know that it indeed is a `Value`.

I can understand why it doesn't work. I'm just looking for a viable workaround.

Comment: What type is p initially? (I don't understand where Action<T> fits in)

Comment: Action<T> is a field of ProxyWithSetter<T>. It is set to some concrete type when the instance is made, but then all of those instances are shoved into a List<ProxyValue> and that concrete type is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might create this interface:

```
interface IProxyWithSetter
{
    Action<Value> Setter { get; }
}
```

And implement it something like:

```
class ProxyWithSetter<T> : ProxyValue, IProxyWithSetter where T : Value
{
    Action<Value> IProxyWithSetter.Setter { get { return x => this.Setter((T)x); } }

    //other things
}
```

That way, in a context where the type is statically known, your `Setter` will take a `T`, but in your method you're speaking of, you can do an `as IProxyWithSetter` and then call `Setter(val)`.

Comment: This is as close (and perhaps more elegant) to my final solution as it gets. I'll mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get information about the types using

```
p.GetType()
```

Using this, you'd get a Type-object whose string-representation is something like

```
ProxyWithSetter[Value]
```

You can access the generic type with

```
p.GetType().GenericTypeArguments
```

an array consisting of all Type-objects which are generic parameters for your class.
Then just check

```
p.getType().GenericTypeArguments == typeof(Value)
```

Comment: But the actual checking which ProxyValue is a ProxyWithSetter isn't the problem. I've solved that differently in my solution. The problem is that I need to cast it to it's "true" type so I can call a generic function it has as a field. Also, I need to pass a Value to that function, so even if I managed to cast it, I'd still need to cast the value to the appropriate type...

Comment: I tried it out. When the types (incl. generic arguments) are correct, everything works fine. Could you provide the crashing code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're asking.  Even if you made a contravariant interface containing `Setter` (which would have to be a property, not a field), it would only be able to take items of type `T` or more derived.

For instance, if you have a class `SuperValue` which subclasses `Value` and then you have an instance of `ProxyWithSetter<SuperValue>`, you cannot pass an instance of `Value` to it.  It MUST be `SuperValue` or something subclassing `SuperValue`.

So the problem is that not every `ProxyWithSetter<T>` can accept an input of type `Value` to its `Setter`.